# Multiplying a variable (textbox) by a number and sending an alert based on the inputs in textboxes if certain conditions have been met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written javascript code that is meant to alert the user if certain conditions are met within textboxes. If those conditions are met the variable 'singlenum' should multiply by 40 and be part of the alert that the webpage (currently doesn't) sends.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>West London Boats</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A company based in West London, offering high quality boat voyages down the Thames">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function weclicked() {
    var singlenum = document.getElementById("singlenum").value;
    var tickettype = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
    var areanum = document.getElementById("areanum").value;
    if (tickettype == "adult" && areanum == 1) {
      (singlenum * 40) {
        alert ("Your booking has been placed, you should recieve an email with your details shortly. Your booking is: " + singlenum + " adult ticket(s) to Area " + areanum + ". This will cost: " + singlenum * 40 + ".");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<body>
  <section class="book" id="book">
    <div><p><br></p>
      <div class="container group">
        <h3>Book</h3>
        <form>
          <fieldset class="group">
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Name">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@address.com">
            </div>
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="value" id="singlenum" placeholder="Number of single tickets"/>
            </div>
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="value" id="areanum" placeholder="Area number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="value" id="tickettype" placeholder="Adult, child or concession"/>
            </div>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Any queries?"></textarea>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="button">
            <button type="button" onClick="weclicked()" id="button">Book</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I don't know why nothing happens and have trawled through various websites and questions for the last two days looking for the answer, having found nothing I now beg the community to spare a moment to help me. Can you tell me how to fix my code, why it didn't work and how you fixed it? Much appreciated.

Comment: You have a syntax error in the first line of condition block

Comment: Solved as of 29/10/15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the improvement that Nitin offered, I was able to come up with a solution.
The javascript section should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function weclicked() {
var singlenum = document.getElementById("singlenum").value;
var tickettype = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
var areanum = document.getElementById("areanum").value;

if (tickettype.toLowerCase() == "adult" && areanum == 1) 
 singlenum2 = singlenum * 40 ;

 alert ("Your booking has been placed, you should recieve an email with  your details shortly. Your booking is: " + singlenum + " adult ticket(s) to Area " + areanum + ". This will cost: " + singlenum2 + ".");


}

</script>
```

This uses the new term 'singlenum2' to hold the equation 'singlenum * 40'. It allows the user to see the number of single tickets that have been issued and the cost of them, without using the equation to apply the number of single tickets as well.

Thank you so much to everyone who answered my plea for help, I really appreciated it. Enjoy your day!

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
if (tickettype.toLowerCase() == "adult" && areanum == 1) {
    singlenum *= 40; // check if it's correct for your logic
    alert ("Your booking has been placed, you should recieve an email with your details shortly. Your booking is: " + singlenum + " adult ticket(s) to Area " + areanum + ". This will cost: " + singlenum * 40 + ".");
}
```

Not sure if you want to multiply `singlenum` by 40 two times, it's your call.

Also add `.toLowerCase()` to `tickettype` in the `if` condition so that all "adult", "Adult", "ADULT", etc. get covered.

http://jsfiddle.net/tzz4ah5n/3/

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it and there was still no alert. Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: I looked over your code and it resulted in the number of single tickets being 40 (should be 1) and the cost as 1600 (should be 40). The reason for this is that the number of single tickets should be the number that the user input in the first place, not the result of the equation. The second part was incorrect because you repeated the equation, resulting in 1 being multiplied by 40 and then by 40 again (essentially 40^2). To fix this you'd need to have the equation only happen once and have the term changed to refer only to the second use of 'singlenum' in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.
Just Made Some Simple Modifications and For me it is Working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>West London Boats</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A company based in West London, offering high quality boat voyages down the Thames">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function weclicked() {
    var singlenum = document.getElementById("singlenum").value;
    var tickettype = document.getElementById("tickettype").value;
    var areanum = document.getElementById("areanum").value;
    if (tickettype == "adult" && areanum == 1) 
     singlenum= singlenum * 40 ;
   alert ("Your booking has been placed, you should recieve an email with  your details shortly. Your booking is: " + singlenum + " adult ticket(s) to Area " + areanum + ". This will cost: " + singlenum + ".");
 }
</script>
<body>
  <section class="book" id="book">
    <div><p><br></p>
      <div class="container group">
        <h3>Book</h3>
        <form>
          <fieldset class="group">
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Name">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@address.com">
            </div>
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="value" id="singlenum" placeholder="Number of single tickets"/>
            </div>
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="value" id="areanum" placeholder="Area number"/>
            </div>
            <div class="column form-left">
              <input type="value" id="tickettype" placeholder="Adult, child or concession"/>
            </div>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Any queries?"></textarea>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="button">
            <button type="button" onClick="weclicked()" id="button">Book</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This Code will give alert everytime user is booking tickets as per the requirement and also for the specific conditions that you have mentioned (singlenum should be multiplied by 40 on adult and area number 1) will work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I change the code so that the alert outputs the first 'singlenum' as the original, non-multiplied number? For example, if the number to be multiplied by 40 was one, how could I make the alert read: Your booking is: 1 adult ticket(s) to Area 1. This will cost: 40.

Comment: glad i could help you.